# How to store and retrieve multiple NSStrings in NSData

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata

Is there any way I can store and retrieve multiple text strings in an `NSData` object?

I am looking into external accessories and just wondering how multiple arbitrary parameters are transmitted to and from the devices.

I assume that they will need to be decoded into `NSString` objects from an `NSData` object. So is there any way to distinguish between separate `NSString` objects from one stream of data?

Or, will multiple string parameters be stored in separate `NSData` objects? With a buffer for each?

Thanks

Comment: to distinguish you can use non-printable characters.

Comment: can you give an example please? You mean the string will look like this: "first|second|third|fourth" and I split by the "|"?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on your use case? What kind of devices are involved? Do both sides speak Objective-C? Can you freely specify the protocol?

Comment: yes somthing like this...

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe an iPhone communicating with an external accessory - an MFI third party device. I know nothing more at this stage in time. The third party device will be platform independent, so it will communicate with Android devices as well. The communication will presumably be in HEX.

Comment: Good old ASCII has a character (non-printable) intended as a record separator (0x1E). You could use that one, for instance. Should be fairly platform agnostic.

Comment: @monolo that might be useful! Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like this question can not be answered without further knowledge about the device in question. I presume you cannot design/change the firmware of the device to use a schema proposed here.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe that is a potential option - but in order to suggest changes I need to understand the options available to me, some of which I have now. Until then, its just a case of me finding out all the potential ways this could work and having them in my arsenal for when we get a device to test with.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSKeyedArchiver to to archive an array of NSStrings.

```
+ (NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)rootObject
```

[NSKeyedArchiver Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html)